# display my dropdown box in a specific area

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok here's what I am doing. Based on some dropdown value I am craeting another dropdown value.
Is it possible to display that dropdown in some specific area as I wish based on my existing code.

```
        if (SelectedIndex == 2 || SelectedIndex == 5 || SelectedIndex == 7) {
            $("#DomContainer").remove();
            var MainContainer = document.createElement("Div");
            MainContainer.id = "DomContainer";
            $("body").append(MainContainer);                
            var Options = new Array();
            for(var i=1;i<=28;i++){
               Options.push(i);
            }
            AddDropDown(Options);
        }

    function AddDropDown(Options) {
        var selectHTML = "<label>Day:</label>&nbsp;";
        selectHTML += "<select>";
        for (i = 0; i < Options.length; i = i + 1) {
            selectHTML += "<option value='" + Options[i] + "'>" + Options[i] + "</option>";
        }
        selectHTML += "</select>";
        document.getElementById("DomContainer").innerHTML = selectHTML;
    }

For example <div id="new_drop">//Display the drop down here </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a second parameter to `AddDropDown` for passing the ID of the container to which you want to insert your dropdown list:

```
function AddDropDown(Options, containerId) {
    ...
    document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = selectHTML;
```

Then call it like this:

```
AddDropDown(Options, "new_drop");
```

(if I understand you correctly)

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove and append elements from the DOM, just replace the existing element contents ... here's a simplified version.

```
// if "SelectedIndex" is one of the values in the array provided
if ($.inArray(SelectedIndex, [2,5,7])) {
        $("#DomContainer").html("<label>Day:</label>&nbsp;"+inject_dropdown(28));
}    

// Creates and returns a new drop-down based on the "length" provided
function inject_dropdown(length){
    var selectHTML = "<select>";
    for( i=1; i<=length; i++ ){
        selectHTML += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>"
    }
    selectHTML += "</select>"
    return selectHTML;
}
```

Replace the `$('#DomContainer')` selector with whatever selector identifies the place you want the new drop-down to appear.